# Loop through array by using another array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have 2 tables, one named `Global_list` and the other named `Payment_history`.

`Global_list` is a list of companies and `Payment_history` is the companies who paid.

I want to extract the global list and compare it to the payment history to see who did not pay for a specific month. My attempts are not successful thus far and I do not know where I am looping incorrectly.

```
$just = array();
$peres = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT(PE_number)
        FROM Payment_history
        WHERE Payment_month = '$_REQUEST[period]' ");

while ($perow = mysqli_fetch_array($peres)) {
    array_push($just, $perow);
};
$globalres = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT PE_number
        FROM Global_list
        WHERE PE_number <> '$just'
        ");

while ($globalrow = mysqli_fetch_array($globalres)) {
    $number = $globalrow['PE_number'];
    $name = $globalrow['PE_name'];
    print ("
            <tbody><tr>
                    <td>$number</td>
                    <td>$name</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            ");
};
```

Comment: Don't be like Tiaan, kids, and put unsafe inputs in your SQL queries. Always use prepared statements.

Comment: Noted, I am new to php and still finding my way. Any advice on this though?